# JUnit ClassCastException

Tags: java, junit

I'm testing this line of code and I'm having a `ClassCastException`:

```
final A a = (A) dao.fetchId(id);
```

A extends the return of `dao.fetchId`.

Here's the code for test:

```
 @Test

 public void test() throws Exception {
    final A a = new A();
    final C c = new C();
    c.setId(2L);
    Mockito.when(dao.fetchId(Matchers.anyLong())).thenReturn(a);
    target.someMethod(c, 2L, 2L, true, true);
}
```

Comment: What is the precise return type of `fetchId`?   Is it compatible with `A` (that is, is whatever object `fetchId` is returning a superclass to `A`)?

Comment: return of fetchId should be C. then A extends C. yes it is compatible with A.

Answer (score 0):

Your relationship seems backwards.  You say that `A` extends `C`, but you're attempting to cast a `C` to an `A`.

One can think of inheritance as "is-a" relationships.  When you say that a class extends another, you're effectively saying that a class "is" the class you're inheriting from.

As an example, a `String` **is an** `Object`, but an `Object` is not necessarily a `String`.

Here's what that looks like in code.  You can read the is-a relationship from right to left.

```
Object string = "I'm a string!";
String object = (String) new Object(); // required to satisfy compilation
```

It's difficult to divine context, since we don't know why you've got this inheritance chain to begin with.  But, for this case, you should return the class you really need.

Comment: here's the heirarchy: 
    > ParentClass - **C**
    > ChildClass - **A**